# python gnuplot read from file

Tags: python, linux, gnuplot

i have a file with the following data the first field is UNIXTimestamp,

```
1351734672.095 25
1351734674.449 52
1351734676.638 612
1351734680.669 44
1351734681.121 16
1351734684.182 15
1351734684.386 17
1351734686.823 16
1351734689.807 22
1351734689.807 28
```

how do i load the x,y from this file to python?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from numpy import *
import Gnuplot

g = Gnuplot.Gnuplot()
g.title('My Systems Plot')
g.xlabel('Date')
g.ylabel('Value')
g('set term png')
g('set out "output.png"')
proc = open("response","r")
databuff = Gnuplot.Data(proc.read(), title="test")
g.plot(databuff)
```

currently this is not working...any ideas??

**UPDATE:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from numpy import *
import Gnuplot

g = Gnuplot.Gnuplot()
g.title('My Systems Plot')
g.xlabel('Date')
g.ylabel('Response')
g('set auto x')
g('set term png')
g('set out "output.png"')
g('set timefmt "%s"')
g('set xdata time')
g('set xtic rotate by 45 scale 1 font ",2"')
g('set key noenhanced')
g('set format x "%H:%M:%S"')
g('set grid')


databuff = Gnuplot.File("repo", using='1:2',title="test")
g.plot(databuff)
```

[image]

The time values on xaxis are overlapping with the graph..any ideas??

Answer (score 3):

Using `Gnuplot.File` instead of `Gnuplot.Data`, it is possible to get the following plot:

[image: output.png]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#from numpy import *
import Gnuplot

g = Gnuplot.Gnuplot()
g.title('My Systems Plot')
g.xlabel('Date')
g.ylabel('Value')
g('set term png')
g('set out "output.png"')
#proc = open("response","r")
#databuff = Gnuplot.Data(proc.read(), title="test")

databuff = Gnuplot.File("response", using='1:2',with_='line', title="test")
g.plot(databuff)
```

---

**UPDATE:**

For the overlap, you can change `45` to `-45` :

```
#g('set xtic rotate by 45 scale 1 font ",2"')
g('set xtic rotate by -45 scale 1 font ",2"')
```

[image]

Comment: No need to import numpy here.  Otherwise +1, better answer than mine.

Comment: I commented the `numpy import` line