# combine histograms in gnuplot (weighted average of bin counts)

Tags: python, numpy, gnuplot, histogram, numerics

let us say I have two pieces of data for the same quantity, each coming with its error. In particular I have two histograms in gnuplot files roughly in the format
`xA yA dyA` for histogram A
`xB yB dyB` for histogram B
(the xA and the xB values are the same)

To increase the precision of the histograms I can "merge them" to get a better estimate of y. In practice I want to obtain an histogram where the y values are the weighted average of the yA and yB values, with weights given by the inverse of their errors.

This is a pretty standard operation in data manipulation and I was expecting that some utility would exist to do this on gnuplot histograms. It turns out that I failed to find this utility ...

So I would like to ask if there is any such program out there that already does this. In case it does not exist I'd like to ask for a suggestion in what language to write this. I have already something that does it in Wolfram Mathematica, but I want now to perform the operation in Unix shell so I was wondering if python would be a good choice to manipulate gnuplot files or there is something more suited.

Thanks,
Roberto

To be more exact I have histograms in a .gnu file that somebody gives me in the format

```
   # comments 
     set title "sqrt(p^2(5)) distribution" font "Helvetica, 20" 
     set xlabel "sqrt(p^2(5))" font "Helvetica, 20" 
     set ylabel "d{/Symbol s}/dsqrt(p^2(5))" font "Helvetica, 20" 
     set xrange [    0.00000:  40.00000] 
     plot "-" with histeps 
        4.50000        3986.18        1.27863 
        5.50000        3986.18        1.27863 
        6.50000        3986.18        1.27863 
    e 

     set title "m(5) distribution" font "Helvetica, 20" 
     set xlabel "m(5)" font "Helvetica, 20" 
     set ylabel "d{/Symbol s}/dm(5)" font "Helvetica, 20" 
     set xrange [    0.00000:  40.00000] 
     plot "-" with histeps 
        4.50000        3986.18        1.27863 
        5.50000        3986.18        1.27863 
        6.50000        3986.18        1.27863 
     e
```

I would like to extract all the data from this file to combine, for instance, the m(5) histogram that I have in several files (combine means do a weighted average, as stated above). Any quick way to read in this data in Python and manipulate the histograms to combine them?

Comment: Its hard to give a proper answer, because you can use any language to do the calculations on-the-fly like `plot '< python myscript.py mydata.dat' using 1:2 with boxes`. Or you could merge your data files with `paste` and then you can do this operation also in gnuplot. Which version works, depends also a bit on the organization and exact structure of your data file (number of points, sorted, etc).

Comment: hello, I agree that the computation itself can be done in any language, but maybe things like Unix shell that would require passing by `bc`, which is doable, but definitively not optimal. So the problem maybe boils down to what programming language offers best capabilities to import the numbers in the .gnu file, then I agree that doing the weighted average is quite easy. Any suggestions about how to get the numbers loaded? I have done this into my mathematica program, based on line-by-line text reading, which is ok, but not so nice, nor fast. That is why I wanted to do again in another program

Comment: You edit somewhat changed your issue, because prior to combining your histograms you must extract the appropriate data set from a gnuplot script, which is a completely different task.

Comment: I agree with that. Maybe I have over-simplified the issue for reporting it here. I have something in python, rather low-level text interpretation, that does exactly what my old Mathematica code did. In the end I think that the ease of string manipulation and math computations of python made it a good choice over bash or C.

Comment: Yes, definitely. Your best option, in my opinion, would be though to ask this "somebody" to use data files, instead of hiding the data in gnuplot scripts. Otherwise you'll get problems every time the scripts are changed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Python and Numpy are a good choice for this. If your files contain only a fixed amount of numbers per line you can use the [numpy.loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) function to read them and [savetxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) to write them. Otherwise you will have to use the general Python IO routines.

Comment: so do I understand correctly that this would mean read the txt or gnu file line-by-line and parse the histograms according to some rules I should specify in python?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I can't find a Python utility that parses Gnuplot files either. I don't know how the gnuplot files look like exactly but it would most likely be easier if you'd have access to the original data.

Comment: it seems then Python has nothing more to offer than an other language. I might well do it in C++ and suffer about the same?

Comment: This gnuplot-py quoted in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204764/python-gnuplot-read-from-file    seems a possibly helpful python module, but is so little documented for this business (documentation is not something I dig out in between  source-code lines) that appears quite steep anyways. I am still trying though ...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use `paste` to merge the two files (assuming, that the x-values are the same and in the same order in both files), and do the calculations in gnuplot.

Consider the two test files `A.txt`

```
1 5 1
2 1 2
```

and `B.txt`:

```
1 3 1
2 4 1
```

Using the script

```
set style fill solid noborder
set boxwidth 0.8 relative

set yrange [0:*]
weighted_avg(yA, dyA, yB, dyB) = ((yA/dyA + yB/dyB)/(1.0/dyA + 1.0/dyB))

plot '< paste A.txt B.txt' using 1:(weighted_avg($2, $3, $5, $6)) with boxes notitle
```

You get the following histogram

[image]