# Reading a gnuplot file from a Python script

Tags: python, gnuplot

I am trying to run my gnuplot commands from a Python script. I came across a suggestion that I can save all the gnuplot commands in a file (with format codes for the variables I need to drop in) and then just read that file in with Python and format it. However, I couldn't find any examples to understand how it's done. Can somebody help me out?

PS: I am using gnuplot version 4.2 and I have already tried using -e pipe but for some reason it doesn't work.
PPS: I would prefer not to use Gnuplot-py package

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204764/python-gnuplot-read-from-file

Comment: I used this [package](http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net/).  It's old but it worked fine.

Comment: I would prefer not to use the Gnuplot-py package. Is there any alternate way?

Answer (score 1):

A simple example: Start with a text file with formatting codes,

```
The {adjective1} {adjective2} {mammal1} has escaped!
```

Then in Python you can substitute values like so:

```
# load the template
with open("template.txt") as inf:
    template = inf.read()

# substitute values
result = template.format(
    adjective1 = "lazy",
    adjective2 = "brown",
    mammal1    = "bear"
)

# save the result
with open("plot.dem", "w") as outf:
    outf.write(result)
```

The `plot.dem` file now contains

```
The lazy brown bear has escaped!
```